# Should I pause Mirroring and stop SQL Server services before running windows updates?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, mirroring

I am running Windows update on my SQL Servers (which are in a Principal-Mirror partnership, in High Safety mode).

I am starting with updating the mirror and I was wondering, to increase safety, should I pause mirroring and stop SQL Server Services and then run Windows Update?  Or is this totally unnecessary?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suggest you to **PAUSE** mirroring and then patch the windows.

Ideally, I would follow below approach :

- If you have a witness configured, turned it OFF as during the patching, if sql server service is restarted or the server reboots, then a witness will initiate a failover.

  ```
  ALTER DATABASE [db_name] SET WITNESS OFF
  ```

  - Always patch the current mirrored server, so if things go wrong, then you atleast have your principal ON.

    - Reboot the mirror server (if necessary)
  - Now failover to the newly patched mirror server. Run below T-SQL on the current Principal server `ALTER DATABASE [your database] SET PARTNER FAILOVER`
  - Once the failover is completed, patch the current mirror (which was originally primcipal)

    - Reboot if necessary
  - Now failback to the original principal server.
  - Add back the witness (if removed from step 1)

    `ALTER DATABASE [db_name] SET WITNESS = 'TCP://[FQDN]:[port_number]'`
  - As a saftey measure, run `DBCC CHECKDB` on your databases.

From [BOL](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677181.aspx) :

[image]

Comment: I thought if Witness and Mirror are unavailable, Principal will refuse all transactions?

Comment: @Dina that is not true. Why would Principal refuse connections ? Readup on [database mirroring](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189852.aspx#Overview) to avoid any confusion.

Comment: Right, I'm confusing myself with this scenario: http://sqlblog.com/blogs/tibor_karaszi/archive/2010/04/16/mirroring-what-happens-if-principal-loses-contact-with-both-mirror-and-wittness.aspx

Comment: @Dina Good point and I can see why the confusion happens. The scenario that the article describes is called **split-brain** scenario. Also, if you see my answer, I have explicitly told to **turn-off the witness**. HTH.

Answer (score 0):

Normally if the updates are SQL based (and certain conditions are met), the program will handle the stopping/starting of related services.